# scala, jsr 223 & compiling

Tags: java, scala, scripting, jsr

I successfully set up small test app using scala via jsr 223 apis (scala 2.8.1 and sling JSR 223 implementation). However, when checked if ScriptEngine implements javax.script.Compilable, i got that is is not.

```
final ScriptEngine eng = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala");
System.out.println(eng instanceof Compilable);
```

Are there any other scala jsr 223 impl that supports script compiling? Thanks.

Comment: small note - eng is not null, it is usable to run scripts via .eval method (tested).

Comment: Yes, officially starting from Scala 2.11. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209995/jsr-223-scala-script-engine for other answers.